# PHPMailer PDF attachment getting corrupted in base64 later

Tags: php, email, base64, phpmailer, fpdf

I have some PHP code that takes in data from an HTML form, creates a PDF (using fpdf), and then e-mails the user that PDF.  I am using PHPMailer to send the pdf file to the user.  This all seems to work fine, with a valid PDF arriving at the specified e-mail address.

In some cases, when users have forwarded on this e-mail to a third party (it's always the same third party), the third party have been reporting the PDF is unreadable (as in corrupt).  It only happens on a small number of occasions, and I can't find a common theme.  The messages are sent to an Office 365 system, which will also be where messages are forwarded from.

The e-mails are normally picked up by my users on their work issues iPad, from where the message will be forwarded.

Having done some digging, I have noticed that the raw content for a message with corrupted PDF look like this (the header of the BASE64 section).  The xxxxx is me.

```
--_005_A421FDCEF50F4B6D813D37045CFF0CBExxxxxx_
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64
Content-Disposition: ATTACHMENT;
    size=1375857;
    modification-date="Thu, 16 Jun 2016 13:18:11 GMT";
    filename=xxxxx92471462.pdf;
    creation-date="Thu, 16 Jun 2016 13:18:11 GMT"
Content-Type: APPLICATION/PDF;
    name=xxxxxbe92471462.pdf
Content-Id: <8D340DC9CB8C174E97F546D602F2FD49@xxxxxx.com>

ReceivedfromDB3PR01MB0729eurprd01prodexchangelabscom101605123byDB3PR01MB0730
eurprd01prodexchangelabscom101605124withMicrosoftSMTPServerTLSid1515118viaMa
ilboxTransportSat11Jun2016103431+0000ReceivedfromDB5PR01CA0007eurprd01prodex
changelabscom10162149145byDB3PR01MB0729eurprd01prodexchangelabscom101605123w
ithMicrosoftSMTPServerTLSid1515118Sat11Jun2016103429+0000ReceivedfromDB3FFO1
1FD045protectiongbl2a01111f4007e04176byDB5PR01CA0007outlookoffice365com2a011
11e40051b717withMicrosoftSMTPServerTLSid1515178viaFrontendTransportSat11Jun2
...
```

It looks to me like somehow a load of mail headers have made their way into the BASE64, hence the attachment becoming mangled.  Later on in the BASE64 it looks like more normal encoded attachment.

I doubt that this is really anything to do with the initial creation from PHPMailer, as the message is fine.  It seems to me that something is mangling the e-mail structure and attachments somewhere further down the line.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Many thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: if the emails get to the original recipient ok, and the corruption is only occuring when they forward it, then it's unlikely to be your code/email causing the problem, and entirely on the user's end.

Comment: You might want to double-check that all of your email headers are terminated with \r\n and not just \n. That is required by the RFC and the headers might not be properly handled by some clients if they end with \n.

Comment: Outlook corrupting content is nothing new. It often makes a mess of things, and those headers (especially that capitalisation) is nothing like what PHPMailer produces. That base64 content is clearly corrupt - there should be nothing readable in it at all.